# C++ header guard not working

Tags: c++, header, include, guard

I'm trying to get my includes working, but everything I try leads to errors. Even using #pragma once doesn't work. Do you know what I made wrong?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "utility/headers/Window.h"
#include "engine/headers/Player.h"
#include "engine/headers/Chunk.h"
```

**ChunkManager.h**

```
#ifndef CHUNK_MANAGER_H
#define CHUNK_MANAGER_H

#include "../../utility/headers/Vector3i.h"
#include "Chunk.h"
#include <map>
class ChunkManager{...}
#endif // CHUNK_MANAGER_H
```

**Chunk.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CHUNK_H
#define CHUNK_H

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "CubeCreator.h"
#include "ChunkManager.h"
#include "../../utility/headers/Random.h"
#include "../../utility/noise/headers/Noise.h"

class Chunk{...}
#endif // CHUNK_H
```

Error message is *'ChunkManager' has not been declared*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also missing semi-colons (i.e. `class X { ...};`)

Comment: 'ChunkManager' has not been declared|

Comment: That does not look like the include guards are the problem. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: What else? I don't know what's wrong!

Comment: Why do you need both `#pragma once` and explicit hashguards?

Comment: @MohitJain: The thing is neither called "header guard" nor "hash guard" but "include guard". Using an include guard is guaranteed to work everywhere and is needed for correctness, `#pragma once` may optimise compilation times(?).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `#include "ChunkManager.h"` with `class ChunkManager;`.

That's called *forward declaration* and solves problems like class A needs to know about class B and class B needs to know about class A.

Depending on how you use `ChunkManager` in class `Chunk`. A forward declaration might not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That might be the solution but unfortunately I need information about a const static variable in my Chunk.h:      private:int data[ChunkManager::chunkSize][ChunkManager::chunkSize][ChunkManager::chunkSize];

Comment: Maybe the other way will work (i.e. forward declaring class Chunk in ChunkManager.h). If that does not work either, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Since non of the mentioned techniques worked in my case I defined a new header file containing global variables like chunkSize. Maybe it's just impossible to do what I've tried.

However for those who might find this question here's how my imports look now:

**ChunkManager.h**

```
#include "Chunk.h"
```

**Chunk.h**

```
// no includes
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ChunkManager.h"
```

And access to chunkSize isn't done anymore by calling ChunkManager::chunkSize but instead by calling Settings::chunkSize